# Coger substring en cada linea de un fichero en CMD

Tags: cmd, batch

Lo dicho, quería recorrer un fichero.txt línea a línea y volcar a otro fichero cada una de esas líneas quitándole los primeros 9 caracteres y los últimos 2.

Tengo lo siguiente en un .bat pero no termina de funcionar, ¿Veis el error?

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (E:\Prueba\p3.txt) do (
    SET linea=%%a
    SET result= %linea:~9,-2%
    echo %result% >> "E:\Prueba\p1.txt"
)
pause
```

El fichero p3.txt contiene algo de este estilo:

```
:1004400002E00098401C00900A4900988842F8D3C6
:10045000002210210648FFF791FF0020009002E0E3
:100460000098401C0090034900988842F8D3E0E7C8
:1004700000100140A0860100880400080028002028
:08048000600200006C0100089D
```

A la salida obtengo:

```
ECHO está desactivado.
```

Comment: Obtengo el mismo resultado pero con "ECHO está activado. " Gracias por el interés ;)

Answer (score 3):

SOLUCIONADO!

El error era que dentro de los `for` para que detecte las variables como tal, se deben poner entre `!` en lugar de entre `%` y utilizar `echo(` en lugar de `echo`.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (E:\Prueba\p3.txt) do (
    SET linea=%%a
    SET result= !linea:~9,-2!
    echo(!result! >> "E:\Prueba\p1.txt"
)
pause
```